# Is it possible to add Native Extensions to Actionscript Library projects?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I've got an *ActionScript Library* project which is shared between an *ActionScript* and an *ActionScript Mobile* project. It works nicely for sharing everything I need in the two projects, but I'd now like to share an Adobe Native Extension between the two projects.

There's a 'Native Extensions' tab for adding them on the [ActionScript Build Path] screen in both the *AS* and *AS Mobile* projects, but not the *ActionScript Library* project.

I tried adding the ANE via the 'Add SWC' dialog on the [Build Path] screen in the Library project (there is a filter for *.ane on the file browser), but the project then failed to run with a `VerifyError: Error #1014: Class myANE could not be found.`

Does anyone know if it is possible to add ANEs to *ActionScript Library* projects, or can they only be added directly to *ActionScript* or *ActionScript Mobile* projects?

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Flash Builder, no. You can do it in IntelliJ (I am in the middle of trying to make the switch right now and that has been a fantastic feature so far). If your ANE is open source, as quite a few are, it is likely the SWC used by the dev to compile the ANE is included in the source code, or you could generate yourself. The SWC is the only portion of the ANE required to compile any kind of AIR app or library. You'll have runtime errors if you don't include the ANE in the app, but that is a given regardless.

So if you have the SWC or can compile one, add that as an external library to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the input Josh. I've now got access to the code for the ANE (It's a Flex Library project), and have added a reference to it in my ActionScript Library project. The FlashBuilder IDE then seems happy with the type, but at run time it fails with `VerifyError: Error #1014: Class :MyANE could not be found.` and no further details. I've tried copying the .as files into a AS Lib project to share between the ANE and other AS Lib project, but that fails to compile as the AS Lib project doesn't have access to the `flash.external.ExtensionContext` type used in the ANE code. Sigh.

Comment: Make sure you include the AIR libs in your project, too. That's an option when you first set up a library project.

Comment: Yep, it was down to a combination of missing the AIR Libs, and not having the following extension config in the app.xml file `<extensions>
        <extensionID>foo.foo.myANE</extensionID>
    </extensions>`. I'm not entirely sure why this wasn't added. The app.xml file is under source control, so perhaps it being read only caused the update to fail silently when adding the ANE reference? Got there in the end anyway, hurrah! Thanks as ever Josh.